# Sending back Av-Pair attr free radius

Tags: linux, openldap, cisco, freeradius

I have freeradius configured with Microsoft ldap, I use it to authenticate a user and also check for groups.

in

```
sites-enabled/default
```

under post-auth, I have an if statement such as

```
if(LDAP-Group == "OU=groupA,....."){
   update reply{
       Cisco-AVpair = "shell:priv-lvl=15"
   }
}
```

Is this correct location to handle something like this, I would assume that it should go into the policy.conf but I am not sure how to call it.

help please!!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the correct location. If the same policy code is used in multiple places then it can be placed in policy.conf as a named policy. This policy can then be called as you would a module in authorize, authenticate or post-auth.

```
policy {
    my_policy {
        ...
    }
}

post-auth {
    my_policy
}
```